# discord.py role command with emote

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a role with an emote,  `Staff`, I tried with `:8ball: Staff` and  `Staff` but the command isn't working
Is there any way of the command working with the current role? Cause the admins don't want to change the emotes

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(' Staff')
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is a test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're able to check via the role's ID too:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(id=112233445566778899)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is a test")
```

---

**References:**

- [`commands.has_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role)